# Android - AdMob Banner Crashes App

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After numerous of times trying to fix multiple amount of errors, I've gotten rid of many errors, but more have came up. I'm completely new to AS and Java, so it may be an easy-to fix problem. I think I'm missing a few classes. Therefore, this is the output:

> Error:(79, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable mAdView
>
> Error:(79, 45) error: cannot find symbol variable ad_view
>
> Error:(89, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable mAdView
>
> Error:(140, 19) error: variable adRequest is already defined in method onCreate(Bundle)
>
> Error:(175, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mAdView
>
> Error:(176, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mAdView
>
> Error:(185, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mAdView
>
> Error:(186, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable mAdView

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.xxxx.xxxxx;

//import com.xxxx.xxxxx.R;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;

import java.util.Random;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ScrollTabHolder, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private static AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator sSmoothInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

    private KenBurnsView mHeaderPicture;
    private View mHeader;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip mPagerSlidingTabStrip;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView title;
    private ImageView icon;
    private int mActionBarHeight;
    private int mMinHeaderHeight;
    private int mHeaderHeight;
    private int mMinHeaderTranslation;
    private ImageView mHeaderLogo;
    private RectF mRect1 = new RectF();
    private RectF mRect2 = new RectF();
    private TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    private SpannableString mSpannableString;
    private AlphaForegroundColorSpan mAlphaForegroundColorSpan;

    int[] photos={R.drawable.photo1, R.drawable.phpto2, R.drawable.photo3, R.drawable.photo4, R.drawable.photo5, R.drawable.photo6, R.drawable.photo7, R.drawable.photo8, R.drawable.photo9};
    KenBurnsView imageView;

    /* =====================ADS===================== */
    AdView adView;
    /* =====================ADS===================== */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*/
//
        // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
        // values/strings.xml.
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);

        // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
//
        mMinHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_header_height);
        mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
        mMinHeaderTranslation = -mMinHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView =(KenBurnsView) findViewById(R.id.header_picture);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mSpannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.actionbar_title));

        mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_thumbnail);
        mHeader = findViewById(R.id.header);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPagerAdapter.setTabHolderScrollingContent(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(0xffffffff);
        ViewHelper.setAlpha(getActionBarIconView(), 0f);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int i=0;
            public void run() {
                // change images randomly
                Random ran=new Random();
                int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
                //set image resources
                imageView.setImageResource(photos[i]);
                i++;
                if(i>photos.length-1)
                {
                    i=0;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 7000);  //for interval...
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 7000); //for initial delay..

        /* =====================ADS===================== */

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        /* =====================ADS===================== */
    }
    /* =====================ADS===================== */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /* Called before the activity is destroyed
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    */
    /* =====================ADS===================== */
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> scrollTabHolders = mPagerAdapter.getScrollTabHolders();
        ScrollTabHolder currentHolder = scrollTabHolders.valueAt(position);
        currentHolder.adjustScroll((int) (mHeader.getHeight() + ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mHeader)), mHeaderHeight);

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(ScrollView view, int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY, int pagePosition)
    {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == pagePosition)
        {
            mHeader.setTranslationY(Math.max(-view.getScrollY(), mMinHeaderTranslation));
            float ratio = clamp(mHeader.getTranslationY() / mMinHeaderTranslation, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            interpolate(mHeaderLogo, getActionBarIconView(), sSmoothInterpolator.getInterpolation(ratio));
            setTitleAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void adjustScroll(int scrollHeight,int headerTranslationY) {
        // nothing
    }



    public static float clamp(float value, float max, float min) {
        return Math.max(Math.min(value, min), max);
    }

    private void interpolate(View view1, View view2, float interpolation) {
        getOnScreenRect(mRect1, view1);
        getOnScreenRect(mRect2, view2);

        float scaleX = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.width() / mRect1.width() - 1.0F);
        float scaleY = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.height() / mRect1.height() - 1.0F);
        float translationX = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.left + mRect2.right - mRect1.left - mRect1.right));
        float translationY = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.top + mRect2.bottom - mRect1.top - mRect1.bottom));

        ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view1, translationX);
        ViewHelper.setTranslationY(view1, translationY - ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mHeader));
        ViewHelper.setScaleX(view1, scaleX);
        ViewHelper.setScaleY(view1, scaleY);
    }

    private RectF getOnScreenRect(RectF rect, View view) {
        rect.set(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
        return rect;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public int getActionBarHeight() {
        if (mActionBarHeight != 0) {
            return mActionBarHeight;
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        }else{
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        }

        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(mTypedValue.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        return mActionBarHeight;
    }

    private void setTitleAlpha(float alpha) {
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan.setAlpha(alpha);
        mSpannableString.setSpan(mAlphaForegroundColorSpan, 0, mSpannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        title.setText(mSpannableString);
    }

    private ImageView getActionBarIconView() {
        return icon;
    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> mScrollTabHolders;
        private final String[] TITLES = { "Home", "Install", "About", "Media", "Survey", "Upcoming", "News", "Help", "Credits", "Share", "More"};
        private ScrollTabHolder mListener;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mScrollTabHolders = new SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder>();
        }

        public void setTabHolderScrollingContent(ScrollTabHolder listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            ScrollTabHolderFragment fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) ScrollViewFragment.newInstance(position);
            mScrollTabHolders.put(position, fragment);
            if (mListener != null) {
                fragment.setScrollTabHolder(mListener);
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        public SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> getScrollTabHolders() {
            return mScrollTabHolders;
        }

    }

    public class LinkButtons extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

        public void goToSo (View view) {
            goToUrl ( "http://stackoverflow.com/");
        }

        public void goToSu (View view) {
            goToUrl ( "http://superuser.com/");
        }

        private void goToUrl (String url) {
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
            startActivity(launchBrowser);
        }

    }

}
```

Do I have missing classes? Please be descriptive with my error and if there's a solution.

Example used: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/BannerExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/bannerexample/MyActivity.java

Comment: Please excuse my improper instruction. I'm quite new here. Also, I edited the question as I'm confused on what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the same method onCreate() twice. remove onCreate or change method name

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```